# Ninject Binding With Generics and Mongo

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, ninject

I am trying to inject a MongoCollection into my repository layer like so.

```
Func<Type, string> namingStrategy = x => x.Name;
            Kernel.Bind(typeof(MongoCollection<>))
             .ToMethod(
              x => x.Kernel.Get<MongoDatabase>().GetCollection(x.Request.Target.Type, namingStrategy(x.Request.Target.Type)));
```

What that should do, is bind every MongoCollection<> to it's implementation by getting the collection object from our MongoDatabase object. This "kinda" works, but I get this error :

```
Unable to cast object of type 'MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollection`1[MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollection`1[Profile]]' to type 'MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollection`1[Profile]
```

Notice the type it's casting from is double generic'd. e.g.

```
MongoCollection<MongoCollection<Profile>>
```

I'm unsure how it's getting that deep from the ninject code I've written.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of, when you look closely at the error, it states that you've got an object (instance) of type

```
MongoCollection<MongoCollection<Profile>>
```

which can't be casted to

```
MongoCollection<Profile>
```

This shows us that it's not an issue with the request, and it's not an issue with ninject - because ninject want's `MongoCollection<Profile>` and tries to cast the result of `ToMethod` to this type. But the Func you passed to `ToMethod` returns a `MongoCollection<MongoCollection<Profile>>`.
But Why?

```
x.Request.Target.Type
```

Is `MongoCollection<Profile>`! Now `MongoDatabase.GetCollection` does expect to be passed `Profile`, so that's what's wrong.
So what you have got to do is to use:

```
x.Request.Target.Type
    .GetGenericArguments()
    .Single();
```

instead. It will return `Profile`.